# if neither f nor g is differentiable at x=a. is $f+g$ differentiable at $x=a$?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are defined on R and that neither f nor g is differentiable at x=a.  prove or disprove: f+g is not differentiable at x=a.

I know how to show if f and g are differentiable at x=a.then f+g is differentiable at x=a. But in this problem I don't know how to use definition of differentiable function to prove it. I can't find counterexample to disprove it either.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be bad at $a$. Let $g(x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: Let f(x) be non-differentiable at x=a, but differentiable everywhere else. Let g(x)=-f(x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f$ is not differentiable at $a$, then $-f$ is also not differentiable at $a$.

Comment: But how can we prove this?

Comment: Use the fact that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ does not exist, and note that $\frac{-f(x)-(-f(a))}{x - a} = -\left(\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}\right).$ Then you should be able to show that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{-f(x)-(-f(a))}{x - a}$ does not exist directly.