# if neither f nor g is differentiable at x=a. is $f+g$ differentiable at $x=a$?(2)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

if neither f nor g is differentiable at x=a. is $f+g$ differentiable at $x=a$?

**My answer:**
yes it is differentiable , because according to this question here: [if neither f nor g is differentiable at x=a. is $f+g$ differentiable at $x=a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547252/if-neither-f-nor-g-is-differentiable-at-x-a-is-fg-differentiable-at-x-a)

If $f$ is not differentiable then $-f$ is not differentiable (but I do not understand exactly why ? may be because f is not differentiable meaning that the limit of differentiability does not exist for f and hence it trivially does not exist also for -f ..... am I correct? ). now f+(-f) = 0 which is a differentiable function .... am I correct?

Comment: What if $g \neq -f$?

Comment: I think it is will be false but how to prove it ? @Randall

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if neither f nor g is differentiable at x=a. is $f+g$ differentiable at $x=a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547252/if-neither-f-nor-g-is-differentiable-at-x-a-is-fg-differentiable-at-x-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition of being non-differentiable is reflected in the inequality of Dini derivatives,

$$D^+f(a) = \limsup_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \\ D_+f(a) = \liminf_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \\ D^-f(a) = \limsup_{h \to 0-}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\\ D_-f(a) = \liminf_{h \to 0-}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

The four  Dini derivatives always exist (possibly as extended real numbers), but only when all are equal is the function differentiable.

Note that $D^+f(a) = - D_+(-f)(a),$ etc.,  and it is then easy to show that if any two Dini derivatives of $f$ are not equal, then a pair of Dini derivatives of $-f$ are not equal.

Comment: Somewhat of an intentional overkill since directly from the definition the existence of $f'$ implies the existence of $(-f)'$.